Does DDR5 on-die ECC report/count fixed errors?
Simple question.
Full ECC reports count of corrected and uncorrected errors to operating system, these are easy to see.
DDR5 now provides new ODECC (on-die ECC) error correction that is internal to RAM chips and also corrects errors (or not). Does ODECC provide way for OS to see how many errors were corrected/uncorrected by this new mechanism?
If I get DDR5 ECC sticks, I obviously will see correction counts from the regular ECC, but what about this new in-chip layer?
